# Javascript obejct merge+add algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, javascript-objects

I was trying to merge & add these two objects like this :

```
obj1 = {
  jpg: 1,
  gif: 3,
}

obj2 = {
  jpg: 1,
  avi: 5,
}

obj3 = mergeAdd(obj1, obj2);
// obj3 = {
//   jpg: 2,
//   gif: 3,
//   avi: 5,
// }
```

First, I create this which takes O(n^2) likes :

```
for (let foo in obj1) {
  for (let bar in obj2) {
    if (foo === bar) {
      // Exists : Add count
      obj1[bar] += obj2[bar];
    } else {
      // Don`t Exists : Copy from obj2
      obj1[bar] = obj2[bar];
    }
  }
}
```

And then, one 'new idea' came into my mind - using hash function :

1. Get hash value for 'key' of obj1 & obj2.
2. Insert or add 'value' of obj1 & obj2 to new array using their hash value as an index of the array.
3. Make the array into new object.

What I want to know :

1. Is there any library which have function like mergeAdd(obj1, obj2)?
2. Is my 'new idea' faster than mergeAdd(obj1, obj2)?
3. What is the fastest algorithm to do mergeAdd?

Thanks!

Comment: O(nlogn) for merging and sorting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution with linear complexity.

```js
var obj1 = { jpg: 1, gif: 3, },
    obj2 = { jpg: 1, avi: 5, },
    merged = function (array) {
        var r = {};
        array.forEach(function (a) {
            Object.keys(a).forEach(function (k) {
                r[k] = (r[k] || 0) + a[k];
            });
        });
        return r;
    }([obj1, obj2]);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(merged, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to use ES6? you can do this easily with the new Object.assign() method:

```
let newObj = Object.assign({}, obj1, obj2);
```

without ES6:

```
var newObj  = {};
obj1 = {
  jpg: 1,
  gif: 3,
};

obj2 = {
  jpg: 1,
  avi: 5,
};
Object.keys(obj1).forEach(function(k) {
    newObj[k] = obj1[k];
});
Object.keys(obj2).forEach(function(e) {
    newObj[e] = obj2[e];
});
```

working fiddle: https://jsbin.com/rogada/edit?js,console

taken from: http://es6-features.org/#ObjectPropertyAssignment

Answer (score 0):

A generic recursive/functional solution. Takes an array of objects and merges each one into an output object. No idea how performant it is compared to the other answers though - it's probably pretty bad.

```
function addValues(obj) {
  return function (p, c) {
    p[c] = (p[c] || 0) + obj[c];
    return p;
  }
}

function mergeObject(obj, out) {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce(addValues(obj), out);
}

function processArray(arr, fn, out) {
  out = out || {};
  if (!arr.length) return out;
  out = fn(arr.shift(), out);
  return processArray(arr, fn, out);
}

var arr = [{ jpg: 1, gif: 3 }, { jpg: 1, avi: 5, }];
processArray(arr, mergeObject); // { jpg: 2, gif: 3, avi: 5 }
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/hjeawkyz/5/)